# System.currentTimeMills() возвращает слишком большое значение

Tags: java

Я пишу свой JUnit, пробую сделать тестирование времени. 
Написал для этого вот такой класс:

```
public class MyTimeTester extends MyTestCase{

private long timeout;

public MyTimeTester(long timeout) {
    this.timeout = timeout;
}

public void testTime(){
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    doSomething();
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime;
    if(Math.abs(endTime - startTime) > timeout){
        throw new AssertionError("overtime: expected "+timeout+"ms, but was "+(Math.abs(endTime-startTime))+"ms");
    }
}

protected void doSomething() {

}

}
```

Наследуюсь от него:

```
public class TestMyTestTimer extends MyTimeTester{

public TestMyTestTimer(long timeout) {
    super(timeout);
}

@Override
public void doSomething(){
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

То есть получается что тестовый метод будет выполнять 2000 миллисекунд.
Создаю объект класса:

```
TestMyTestTimer test3 = new TestMyTestTimer(1000);
```

Потом добавляю его в TestSuite и запускаю.
Получается такая картина:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Число, которое после but was на скрине - это должно быть время выполнения тестового метода. То есть примерно 2000ms. А получилось очень огромное. Почему? Причем, если я убираю Math.abs() в классе MyTimerTest, там получается примерно такое же число но со знаком минус.

Comment: По-моему два раза отняли. Первый раз в определении endTime, и потом еще раз при выводе и сравнении.

Comment: @hinotf Не желаете оформить в виде ответа, т.к. проблема определенно в этом? :)

Comment: @hinotf, Да, проблема в этом, голова уже кипит под вечер) спасибо)

Comment: Переоформил комментарий в виде ответа.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема в том, что Вы отняли значение два раза. Первый раз в определении endTime, и потом еще раз при выводе и сравнении.